# How many requests can one Google App Engine Instance handle?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a simple Cloud Endpoints Restful API that does simple things add an entity, update and entity, delete an entity, search for an entity.

My question is how much traffic can one Google App Engine instance handle? That is, how many API requests before you need another instance?

I know there are different [instance classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes) so let's just use the default `B4` one (memory: 512 MB, CPU Limit: 2.4 GHz)

And I also know this may be a difficult question to answer but given the simple API I described above, could anyone enlighten me on what might be the average number of requests one instance could handle (let's just assume I am not using memcache or any other optimizations)?

Any links to specific documentation would also help greatly, as I am a little confused.

Thank you!

Comment: I don’t think you are going to have an answer for this. It depends on 1. what you are doing and 2. how much you care about performance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"you need another instance"*?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing

Comment: One way to do a real world check is to spin up a virtual machine. Something like VPSDime or a Google VM would do. Then install Apache Bench and hit your endpoint with different numbers of concurrent requests and different numbers of requests. Watch to see when response time becomes unacceptable

Comment: Use this: ab -n 100 -c 10 'https://example.com/myendpoint'
The number of requests in this case is 100 and 10 requests will be made concurrently.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Well app engine can have many instances. You can start of with one and it can spin up more app engine instances as performance drops. All costing more of course as you get more.

Comment: @natario 1: I wrote up the simple api which just gets/inserts/queries a simple entity in datastore. 2: Just wondering how much an instance can handle in terms of requests before it automatically spins up another one (e.g. GAE has determined performance has dropped)

Comment: @Just1689 Not sure what you are talking about haha can you clarify?

Answer (score 7):

GAE will dynamically spawn more service instances automatically only if the service is configured for automatic or basic scaling, but not for manual scaling.

From [Scaling dynamic instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_dynamic_instances):

> The App Engine scheduler decides whether to serve each new request with an existing instance (either one that is idle or accepts
>   concurrent requests), put the request in a pending request queue, or
>   start a new instance for that request. The decision takes into account
>   the number of available instances, how quickly your application has
>   been serving requests (its latency), and how long it takes to spin up
>   a new instance.
>
> Each instance has its own queue for incoming requests. App Engine monitors the number of requests waiting in each instance's queue. If
>   App Engine detects that queues for an application are getting too long
>   due to increased load, it automatically creates a new instance of the
>   application to handle that load.

The actual behaviour also depends on the respective scaling mode configuration parameters, see [Change auto scaling performance settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/managing-resources#change_auto_scaling_performance_settings) and [Scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#scaling_elements). And, of course, on how exactly your app code responds to these requests. Very difficult if not impossible to get an exact number.

But what you can do is to actually attempt to measure it: have a test program access your app with the typical kind of requests and with gradually increasing request load, while you watch, in 2 separate browser windows:

- for new instances being spawned (either by looking for the request logs for those accompanied by the info message indicating that a new instace was started or by checking the instances page)
- the relevant screen in the dashboard summary which will show the app's stats of interest when the instance is started

You could also check **your app's** [request logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) to see how much their handling takes. For some of them you can even see appstats-like tracing in StackDriver. You can also enable [appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) to obtain such figures for *all* your requests.

From these figures you can try to derive some minimum performance values, this time based on the assumption that "instance can handle" means the instance can process the requests fast enough in order to prevent its request queue depth from constantly growing until the instance is killed (which I suspect would be a load level a lot higher than the level triggering dynamic spawning of new instances).

For example handling one type of request in **my app** takes less than 50ms most of the time on an F1 instance. Since I have `threadsafe: true` configured it's possible that handling some requests may overlap (how much - I have absolutely no idea). So I can estimate that the F1 instance could handle upwards of 72000 requests **of that type** per hour. But I also have requests taking on average 1s, the same instance would only be able to handle with certainty some 3600 such requests per hour. As you see *a ballpark* value doesn't really make a lot of sense.

That's why IMHO the dashboard figures are better than estimating, since they are measurements averaged across the **real** range/spread of your app's request types and their **actual** handling. The multithreading gain would be included, for example.

Comment: I see... Much of what you said I have already read but it still does not really answer the question of how many requests can one instance handle (e.g. manual scaling with 1). Is it like 5,000 api calls an hour? Or what? (not yelling at you just in general).  And sometimes new instances are spawned for no reason I have found so just looking at the dashboard may not be scientific enough. Thanks for the write up though. I'll to keep figuring it out.

Comment: measurements are scientific, even if the instrument precision sucks :)

Comment: The point is I am looking for a rough number lol. Hoping someone else has thought about the same thing.